# Pipeline in Azure DevOps for Azure Functions: no functions available

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I've created my pipeline in Azure DevOps for my Azure Functions project. The first interesting problem is the release is not starting when there is a new build ready. I can't understand why.

[image: Artifact]

I can fire the release manually using the build I have just created.

[image]

How you can see, the release has success. The pipeline is like that:

```
steps:
- task: AzureFunctionApp@1
  displayName: 'Deploy Azure Function App'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.AzureSubscription)'
    appType: '$(Parameters.AppType)'
    appName: '$(Parameters.AppName)'
```

[image: Pipeline]

With Kudu I can inspect the wwwroot folder on the server and I find, as I expected, all binary files for this function. The problem is, there is no functions available in the portal and I can call them.

[image: Kudu]

How you can see in the Azure Portal there is not functions available.

[image: Azure Portal]

### Update

I have just noticed there is not the right structure on the file system from the release. I think I did something wrong in the configuration of the pipeline: I select :

- Path to project(s): `**/*.csproj`
- Arguments: `-o publish_output` (to create the build in the *publish_output* folder)

[image: dotnet build]

Then I create the zip to deploy in the release with this parameters:

- Root folder or file to archive: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output`

[image: archive]

PS: what is the difference between `System.ArtifactsDirectory` and `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. In the **Archive** step, I must uncheck `Prepend root folder name to archive paths` (I didn't read this option because it was as default and I didn't pay attention).

- Root folder or file to archive: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output`
- Uncheck `Prepend root folder name to archive paths`
- Archive file to create: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip

> ```
> steps:
> - task: ArchiveFiles@2
>   displayName: 'Archive (zip)'
>   inputs:
>     rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
>     includeRootFolder: false
>     archiveFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
> ```

In the step **Publish Artifact: drop** check:

- Path to publish: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip`

> ```
> steps:
> - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
>   displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
>   inputs:
>     PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
> ```

[image: Archive zip]

Answer (score 0):

> the release is not starting when there is a new build ready.

You probably didnot enable the `Continuous deployment trigger`. See below screen to enable CD trigger for your release pipeline.

[image]

> in the Azure Portal there is not functions available

Azure functions require a specific folder structure to allow the functions to show in Azure portal. You can check if the folder  structure in the /wwwroot folder looks like below. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#functions-class-library-project) for more information.

```
| - bin
 | - MyFirstFunction
 | | - function.json
 | - MySecondFunction
 | | - function.json
 | - host.json
```

Comment: Thank you. I did the `Continuous deployment trigger`. I recreated the pipeline and now it is working. You are right about the structure. I've just noticed there is no structure in Azure. I updated my post.